# ImportError: cannot import name 'contact_view' from 'SCcontact' (app) in Django

Tags: django, python-import, html-email, contact-form

I am new to Django. I'm trying to create a web contact form in Django that confirms by email the receipt of the enquiry to the enquirer and notifies the site owner of the enquiry details.

When I do this I am getting the following error message

File "C:\Users\mikec\OneDrive\Documents\Conted\Web Applications with Python JavaScript and SQL\Sophie Canniffe Costume Design\myproject\myproject\urls.py", line 19, in 
from SCcontact import contact_view
ImportError: cannot import name 'contact_view' from 'SCcontact' (C:\Users\mikec\OneDrive\Documents\Conted\Web Applications with Python JavaScript and SQL\Sophie Canniffe Costume Design\myproject\SCcontact_*init*_.py)

I have a views.py form in my app (SCcontacts) as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def contact_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        message = request.POST.get('message')

        # Send email to the user
        user_subject = "Thank you for your enquiry"
        user_message = f"Dear {name},\n\nThank you for contacting us. I have received your      message and will get back to you soon.\n\nBest regards,\nSophie"
        send_mail(user_subject, user_message, 'noreply@sophiecanniffecostumes.co.uk', [email])

        # Send email to yourself
        admin_subject = "New Sophie Canniffe Costumes website enquiry"
        admin_message = f"You have received a new contact enquiry from:\n\nName: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nMessage: {message}"
        send_mail(admin_subject, admin_message, 'noreply@ophiecanniffecostumes.co.uk', ['sophie_canniffe@yahoo.co.uk'])

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contact'))

    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

and the urls.py in my project (myproject) is as follows

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from SCcontact import contact_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('contact/', contact_view, name='contact'),
]
```

I've tried various configurations of the file path to import from to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from SCcontact.views import contact_view    # NOTE THE CHANGE HERE

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('contact/', contact_view, name='contact'),
]
```

But you're probably better off creating an app-specific **urls.py**, putting it into your SCcontact app's directory:

```py
# SCcontact
# urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.contact_view, name='contact'),
]
```

Then importing those views into your project-wide **urls.py**:

```py
# myproject
# urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include    # NOTE THE CHANGE HERE
# from SCcontact import contact_view     # REMOVE THIS

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('contact/', contact_view, name='contact'),  REMOVE THIS AND REPLACE WITH:
    path('contact/', include('SCcontact.urls')),
]
```

This way you can better organize all your urls of all the apps you will eventually have in your project.  Each app with it's own **urls.py**, then all the individual app **urls** included in the main project **urls.py**.

Comment: Raphael - thanks for the reply - I've tried your suggested changes and I'm now getting the following error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes @MikeC remove the line `from SCcontact import contact_view` from your project-wide **urls.py**.  It is not needed, and incorrect.  I've edited my answer since I missed that.